# Jquery Remove Element from List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list in JQuery that's called additionalInfo, which is filled in using this JQuery function:

```
$('#append').on('click', function () {
//check if the following area is valid before moving on, check the jquery validation library
    var text = $('#new-email').val();
    var li = '<li>' + text +  'input type="hidden" name="additionalInfo" value="'+text+'"/> </li>';
    $('#additional-info-list').append(li);
    $('#new-email').val('');
});
```

The point of the function is not only to store the info in a list that can be used later, but also to render a `<li>` with the info text in it. Right now I have another button on each `<li>` that when pressed, makes the li vanish, but I also need to add code to it that completely removes the info text from the additionalInfo list. This is the code I have for that method so far:

```
$('#removeEmail').on('click', 'li>.remove-btn', function (event){

$(event.currentTarget).closest('li').remove();

});
```

How can I get the segment of info text out of the li and then remove it from additionalInfo?

Comment: Where is the opening "<" for the input?

Comment: `var li = '<li>' + text +  'input type="hidden" name="additionalInfo" value="'+text+'"/> </li>';` missing opening tag for input field

Comment: Looks like some part of the HTML is missing. You are saying that `<li>` has a button in it. I think jsFiddle with the functionality working till now will be helpful.

Comment: where is your `ul` or `ol` element?

Comment: This code was retyped. I know my methods for adding things to the list and rendering them are working fine; I've checked them on my test server and used print statements. What I need help is with the second JQuery function.

Comment: I also think this cannot work, because dynamic added content can only be clicked with `$(document).on('click', '.yourclass', function(){});`

Answer (score 1):

You have few problems. First of all when you create the new items, your markup is not correct. You were missing the opening bracket of input tag. Also i changed the code for delete so that it listens for the click event on any item with class `remove-btn` under the `li` element. This should delete the item when you click the remove link inside the li.

```
$(function(){

  $('#append').on('click', function () {

    var text = $('#new-email').val();
    var li = '<li>' + text +  '<input type="hidden" name="additionalInfo" 
                      value="'+text+'"/>
               <a href="#" class="remove-btn" >remove</a></li>';
    $('#additional-info-list').append(li);
    $('#new-email').val('');

  });

  $(document).on('click', 'li>.remove-btn', function (event){
     var _this =$(this);
     _this.closest('li').remove(); 
  });

});
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsbin.com/femihizuro/edit?html,js,output)